# Can you receive eggs from Pokestops with a full bag?

Tags: pokemon-go

Is it possible to receive an egg from a Pokestop when your bag is at or above its capacity, but there is room for additional eggs?

I tried this 6 or 7 times today while I only had 5 eggs, and did not get any, but this could have just been bad luck.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From my own personal experience you cannot receives eggs from pokestops if your item inventory is full even if you have less than 9 eggs in your pokemon inventory. Some cursory searching doesn't show anyone who has been able to receive eggs when inventory is full.

Source: Personal experience and [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/pokemongo/comments/4t7ojd/if_your_inventory_is_full_can_you_still_recieve/)

Answer (score 0):

From personal experience with the game, if I have 9 eggs in my bag, I cannot receive any more eggs. I don't know if this is documented anywhere, but from playing the game with a full bag of eggs now, I haven't received any new eggs. I doubt it's just bad luck.

Comment: OP was referring that his egg-inventory was not full.

Comment: It is documented in the text "9/9" on the egg screen

Comment: This edit was not in place when my answer was posted.

Comment: -1. This is answering a different question, even prior to the edit. The original version of the question was pretty clear.

Comment: @Ellesedil I suppose I answered too fast, I didn't see the "have less than 9 eggs in your pokemon inventory". I incorrectly assumed the bag also meant the egg part as well.

Answer (score 0):

From my personal experience you cannot receive any eggs with a full bag. I live near the city so I'm able to get the pokestops and after nearly 15 poke stops with a full bag I was not able to get any eggs!