# Whats happening if your pokemon bag is full and egg hatches?

Tags: pokemon-go

If my bag is full with Pokémon, what happens if I try to hatch a Pokémon. I have three ideas:

- The hatched Pokémon will be lost/deleted.
- The bag becomes overloaded. For example 251/250.
- The egg won't hatch until the bag has space.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: 
 http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/275705/can-you-receive-eggs-from-pokestops-with-a-full-bag?s=2|0.8896

Comment: @MakaMido I'm asking about hatching, not collecting eggs

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What happens if you try to catch a pokemon when you are at your pokemon inventory limit?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/282149/what-happens-if-you-try-to-catch-a-pokemon-when-you-are-at-your-pokemon-inventor)

Comment: Its not catching it's hatching man.

Comment: I'm sure I've seen this question here somewhere, but you are right. Neither of the above is a duplicate.

Comment: @DJPirtu The question posted by Zalbis probably shouldn't be considered a duplicate, this one does ask about something else. [One answer on that question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/282149/what-happens-if-you-try-to-catch-a-pokemon-when-you-are-at-your-pokemon-inventor#282158)(and the subsequent comments) does talk about Pokemon limit, though, with respect to hatching eggs when full. May be the cause for the VTC, as any answers on this one will probably reiterate what was discussed on that answer.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

d) None of the above.

Eggs are counted towards your total pokemon count, so will hatch and be added normally.

Comment: That seems a bit weird, considering the "Pokémon" tab has its own count that appears independent of the "9/9" Egg count. So are you saying that you can't actually reach 242/250 if you have 9 Eggs?

Comment: You can, they are already included in the counter which means with 9 eggs if the counter is 241, you have 232 Pokemon and 9 eggs. Its easily noticeable if you always kept exactly one Pokemon from each kind. Your Pokedex will now tell you something like 42seen, 42 cought but your bag tells you 51/ 251.